# How to correctly ignore breaks at throw while debugging c++ program in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, gdb, qt-creator

I'm trying to remote debug a program, which contains a lot of code with

```
try { map.at(invalid_index)}catch(...){}
```

blocks. I've receive a stop each time, even with "catch throw ignore" as startup gdb command.

The breaks take place at stl_map.h at (__throw_out_of_range(__N("map::at")))

```
mapped_type&
      at(const key_type& __k)
      {
    iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
    if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
      __throw_out_of_range(__N("map::at"));
    return (*__i).second;
      }
```

The debugging target is x86-64 embedded platform with custom Ubuntu 14.04 onboard.

Can I do something else to force gdb stop only at my explicit breakpoints (no more 2-3 occurence)?